# Reordering an array based on its existence in another array

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[4,3]
array_wanted=[4,3,1,2,5]
```

I could do this via a mapping and pushing, but i would love to know more elegant ways of doing this.

Answer (score 6):

```
(b & a) + (a - b)
# => [4, 3, 1, 2, 5]
```

And if you are sure that all elements from `b` are present in `a`, union operator `|` seems to return the proper order:

```
b | a
# => [4, 3, 1, 2, 5]
```